# Twitter has no "delete account" button - no mention of data deletion after 30 days of account deactivation - GDPR and European law enforcement

Tags: gdpr, privacy, personal-information

I want to delete my Twitter account. I believe [Article 17(1)(a)](https://gdpr-info.eu/art-17-gdpr/) of GDPR compels Twitter to give me the option to do that.

But Twitter has no "delete account" button. There is only a "deactivate account" button:

[image]

1. Is Twitter compelled to provide me a "delete account" button?
2. If not, how can I enforce my right under Art. 17 of GDPR to have all my personal data removed from their databases?
3. I am an italian citizen. What is the law enforcement agency to which I can complain? I have found [ICO](http://ico.org.uk) but it seems a UK agency. Is there an European agency or an Italian one to which I can complain?

EDIT: Please note the [Twitter notice](https://help.twitter.com/en/managing-your-account/trouble-reactivating-twitter-account) about account deactivation:

> You deactivated your account more than 30 days ago
>
> Users have 30 days to log in to reactivate a previously deactivated
> account. If it has been more than 30 days since you deactivated, you
> will not be able to reactivate your account. Sign up for a new
> account.

There is no mention to the data being deleted after 30 days.

EDIT 2: Twitter has replied to me that:

> Permanent deletion occurs 30 days from the date of account deactivation

Although this is nowhere written in their guides, as far as I can tell.

Comment: The GDPR doesnt even compel companies to have a website or app, let alone a button to delete your data with...

Comment: @Moo fair. How can I ask them to delete my data in accordance with Art. 17.1.(a) of GDPR? Do I have to send a certified email or a normal email from the email address associated with my account is sufficient?

Comment: @Moo your comment is illogical.  Legal requirements may arise when someone does something that they're not required by law to do.  For example, there is no law that requires the café on the corner to sell food and drink, but there is a law that requires businesses that sell food and drink to store perishables such as milk below a certain temperature.

Comment: @phoog right, so?  The point is that there doesnt have to be a “delete button” so people should stop expecting one by default.  In your example its the equivalent of the fridge being on show or hidden out back - or even there just being a bucket of ice sat somewhere to chill the milk.  The point is that its a mistake to make the assumption that there has to be a button and the process has to be that trivial, and this isnt the first question to make the mistake.  Until a court ruling says otherwise, having a website doesnt mean all interactions has to be via that website for GDPR compliance.