# Twitter and account deactivation - Do you have to explicitly ask for account to be deleted if company nowhere says that it will do so?

Tags: gdpr, privacy, data-protection, personal-information

I am trying to delete my Twitter account.

Twitter only has a "deactivate" account button, and no "delete" account button, as I posted [here](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/60355/twitter-has-no-delete-account-button-no-mention-of-data-deletion-after-30-da?noredirect=1#comment125204_60355).

It looks like in the guides posted by Twitter, nowhere is stated that the data will be deleted after 30 days of deactivation.

For instance, this [official Twitter guide](https://help.twitter.com/en/managing-your-account/trouble-reactivating-twitter-account) states that:

> You deactivated your account more than 30 days ago
>
> Users have 30 days to log in to reactivate a previously deactivated
> account. If it has been more than 30 days since you deactivated, you
> will not be able to reactivate your account. Sign up for a new
> account.

There is no mention to user data deletion.

In the [Twitter Privacy Policy](https://twitter.com/en/privacy) point 4.2 states:

> Deletion
>
> We keep Log Data for a maximum of 18 months. If you follow the
> instructions here (or for Periscope here), your account will be
> deactivated. When deactivated, your Twitter account, including your
> display name, username, and public profile, will no longer be viewable
> on Twitter.com, Twitter for iOS, and Twitter for Android. For up to 30
> days after deactivation it is still possible to restore your Twitter
> account if it was accidentally or wrongfully deactivated.
>
> Keep in mind that search engines and other third parties may still
> retain copies of your public information, like your profile
> information and public Tweets, even after you have deleted the
> information from our services or deactivated your account. Learn more
> here.

Again, no mention about user data deletion.

Asked by email, at the third email Twitter has replied to me that:

> Permanent deletion occurs 30 days from the date of account
> deactivation.

1. The GDPR doesn't compel companies to have a website. But if the company do have a website, are they compelled to advertise that data will be deleted after 30 days of account deactivation?
2. Let's say my friend click on "Deactivate account". He never asked to delete his account. Twitter nowhere says in his website that after 30 days from the date of account deactivation data will be deleted. My friend never asked for his data to be deleted (he only asked for his account to be deactivated). Will Twitter delete his data after 30 days, or is it compelled to do so?

Of course I am referring to EU legislation and in particular the GDPR.

Comment: The question does not have an answer in the "duplicate" question because the answer provided there is the result obtained through a Google search of a website not operated by Twitter and is not the actual Twitter policy

Comment: As written this would probably also be closed as *not a question of law*.  Twitter's policy can say a lot of things, and Twitter isn't even constrained by its own policies.  Are you asking whether Twitter in particular is compliant with GDPR?  It's unreasonable to expect a good answer from an outsider, second-guessing the legal and operations teams of a $40BB company.

Comment: Twitter has answered to me: `Hello,

We appreciate your response. We’ve confirmed you own the account, and deactivated it for you!

Accounts are permanently deleted 30 days after deactivation, and any documents you sent us will also be deleted. 

Thanks, 

Twitter`. I still wonder whether if you deactivate your account through the website, they will delete the data after 30 days, since this is not written anywhere in their privacy policy, or if you have to send them an email address

Answer (score 0):

Activating and deactivating an account is very different from deleting data. On the webpage they offer all kind of functions to activate and deactivate an account, which they don't have to. And it's true, there is no way to delete user data. That must be done by contacting them, in this case via the address of their Data Protection Officer in Ireland (given at the end of the privacy policy), exactly as required by GDPR.

On the other hand, if soneone deactivates his account, according to the Twitter Terms of Service, they can delete the account after a certain periode of inactivity (see "Ending These Terms", they don't mention data here!).

Comment: The ["Ending These Terms"](https://twitter.com/en/tos) says that `your account should be removed due to prolonged inactivity`, not that it will be removed after 30 days of account deactivation

Comment: I edited my question to insert Twitter Privacy Notice. Again it says nothing about data deletion.